# T-SQL to make database if it doesn't exist, or use it if it does

Tags: sql-server

I am writing a script to quickly build empty test DBs in SQL. I did this...

```
IF db_id('NewTest') IS NULL CREATE DATABASE NewTest
GO
USE NewTest
GO
```

Of course, since `NewTest` doesn't exist yet, the `USE` fails and thus so does the script. So I tried...

```
IF db_id('NewTest') IS NOT NULL USE NewTest
```

But that fails for the same reason. I guess the `USE` isn't really needed, but it's easy to forget to switch the DB when you open SQLSAdmin so I try to always use it.

Is there an easy out here?

**UPDATE:** The error is `database does not exist` and the cursor is on the `USE`. That is the gist of the error, I created the table and the error no longer occurs of course.
UPDATE UPDATE - that is DB, not table

Comment: Where are you executing your script? If I execute it in SQL Server Management Studio it works fine.

Comment: What is the error you get?

Comment: Yes, I'm in SQLSMS and it is failing. It works fine AFTER the table is created, but that's only if you run it a second time.

Comment: I can't reproduce your issue...

Comment: Did you make the table? If so, then it works fine.

Comment: You keep saying table, but in your question it's about a `DATABASE`. And i ran the script identically as you posted it. Running it multiple times (after the database is there) also works. **So what error are you getting?**

Comment: I didn't have a database named like yours and your first code snippet just worked fine

Comment: You error is about a table... if you only create a database, but do not create any tables, then of course there won't be any tables in it and selecting from the NewTest database would fail since it doesn't have any tables. This has nothing to do with the code snippet you posted. You must create your tables along with your database.

Comment: It is not, that is a typo.

Comment: Then your error is not reproducible in SSMS. If you are using something else that doesn't recognize `GO` as a batch terminator then this error could surface. You stated you are using *SQLSMS* and i'm not sure what that is but it looks like your `GO` isn't being recognized as a `batch` terminator.

Comment: What version of SQL and Management Studio are you using. I think older versions would do some parsing and validation of the whole script before executing.

Comment: The script executes fine. Intellisense complains but you can just ignore that

Comment: I'm onMicrosoft SQL Server Management Studio 12.0.2569.0. When I run it it seems like the debugger is invoking, before anything happens, the execution stops, that line is highlighted in yellow, and it prints the error in the Output area at the bottom.

Comment: Can you just download and install a more recent version of SSMS?

Comment: Go to Tools ... Options ... Query Execution. Select SQL Server and check what is the batch separator that you're using. It could be changed somehow. If you don't have this option, then probably upgrading would be better.

Comment: I don't know, but I gave up and simply ran each portion by hand and that worked fine.

Comment: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/aef2db46-28b4-4356-a7ed-d66e379f1ecb/in-ssdt-how-do-i-create-database-if-it-doesnt-exists?forum=ssdt